# How to prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt \pi$ using Cauchy Integral Formula.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

How to prove that
 $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt \pi \;\; :\;\; \mathrm{Gaussian \; integral}$$

using Cauchy Integral Formula.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Cannot be done with rectangle parallel to the axes. People have succeeded with parallelograms.

Comment: see mathoverflow http://mathoverflow.net/a/105462/454

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge one should use half of the quadrant as a region. For example:

$$
D =  \{(x,y): 0 \leqslant y \leqslant x \}
$$

So one boundary is $y=0$, the second is $y=x$ and the third is an $\frac{\pi}{4}$-arc of a circle with an infinite radius.

Hope this will help you.

UPDATE:

Sorry, I am mistaken. This domain will help you if you want to calculate these integrals:

$$
\int_0^\infty \cos x^2 dx \; \text{ and } \int_0^\infty \sin x^2 dx
$$

So it cannot help you directly, but eventually you will obtain what you need as your integral will be expressed in integrals above. As you can transform your integral in the following way:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx 
$$

You can rotate the x-axis by $\pi/4$ and get the integrals above.